# Chrome forcing ssl on non ssl heroku web application

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, heroku, https

I have an application running on Heroku, and a dns cname entry that points to it. Looks something like this:

```
one.nest.mysite.com --> one-nest-domain.herokuapp.com
```

We also have another site that uses ssl, with a certificate for `*.mysite.com`.

In Chrome 52 right now, when I go to `http://one.nest.mysite.com` (not https), I get redirect to `https://`, and Chrome warns "Your connection is not private, attackers might be ..." etc.

I think I understand the warning (`*.mysite.com` does not cover `one.nest.mysite.com`, but why is https being forced? Is this some cached redirect somewhere? I've tried fully clearing my browser data, but it still happens. I'm also finding in Safari its working fine...

And lastly when I go to `http://one-nest-domain.herokuapp.com` (no https), the app loads fine with no redirect.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that our configuration for our main site, nest.mysite.com, was including subdomains when pinning certificates. So after visiting https://nest.mysite.com, the certificate was stored on the client and pinned to subdomains. Subsequently visiting http://one.nest.mysite.com would use that certificate, which would force ssl and cause the error.

Excluding subdomain pinning from our main server configuration appears to have fixed things. Note that for the fix to propagate, users would have to visit https://nest.mysite.com to refresh the ssl settings, and then http://one.nest.mysite.com worked as expected.

Hope this is useful to someone else. Caveat: I'm no expert on ssl so take my answer with a grain of salt.